# Write a class with language dependent strings

Tags: babel, documentclass-writing

I am unable to make my class strings language dependent using babel.
I have the following minimal example:

file `test-babel.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{test-babel}[2012/10/22 v0.1]

\DeclareOption{spanish}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
      \renewcommand*\conclusionsname{Conclusiones finales}
     }
  \AtEndOfClass{\main@language{spanish}}
}

\DeclareOption{english}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*\conclusionsname{Final conclussions}
  }
  \AtEndOfClass{\main@language{english}}
}

\newcommand\conclusionsname{dumyy}


\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{report}
\newcommand\print{\conclusionsname}
```

I use this test `tex` file:

```
\documentclass{test-babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\print
\end{document}
```

The result of compilation is the word `dummy`, the default value, and not the 
Spanish translation.

Can someone help me to understand how to use `babel` while writing a class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `spanish` option is not passed to the class, to begin with.

I don't think you really need to have class options for this, however. Here is `zunbeltz.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{zunbeltz}[2012/10/22 v0.1]

\providecommand*{\conclusionsname}{Final conclusions}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackagewith{babel}{spanish}{%
    \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand*\conclusionsname{Conclusiones finales}}%
  }{}
  \@ifpackagewith{babel}{english}{%
    \addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\conclusionsname{Final conclusions}}%
  }{}
}


\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{report}
```

and here the test document `zunbeltz.tex`:

```
\documentclass{zunbeltz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\conclusionsname

\selectlanguage{english}
\conclusionsname
\end{document}
```

You'll get

> Conclusiones finales
>   Final conclusions

Comment: Thanks. Your example work fine. But when only one language is used in `zunbeltz.tex`, let's `english`, then there is an error:
`! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option spanish yet.`

Comment: @zunbeltz Compile twice: when you remove a language from a document, the `.aux` file still keeps track of the preceding LaTeX run when the language was loaded.