# "Page" language key/ macro

Tags: macros, babel

How can I access the word "page" in the current language? I want it to say "page" in the header in the current language.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english,german,italian]{babel}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead{
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \else
        \hfill page \thepage
    \fi
    }
}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}

\lipsum[1-50]


\end{document}
```

What I want is to switch `\hfill page \thepage` with `\hfill <macro> \thepage`, where `<macro>` is some language dependent macro.

**NB**: the solution needs to be able to work without `babel` as well, since it will be implemented in a `.cls` file *before* babel is imported. I also want it to work without babel, similar to how `\languagename` works without babel.

I guess one solution wold be to define my own macro using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664072/199568). I just want to know if such a macro for the word "page" already exists, as it then would be unneccecary to define my own macro.

Comment: The macro is `\pagename`, which is set by `babel` when the language is selected. As to what to do without `babel`, an option is to delay the code with `\AtBeginDocument`. At that point you know if `babel` has been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `\providecommand{\pagename}{Page}` as some "hack". If babel is imported, the command gets re-defined (I guess?) and if not then it will fall back to this definition. This way, it will work for more languages than my original answer using `expl3` syntax.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\providecommand{\pagename}{Page}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead{
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \else
        \hfill \pagename\ \thepage
    \fi
    }
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english,german,italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}

\lipsum[1-50]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for sake of comparison, what we can do in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam [lm]

\foreach 
   {en}{Page} {es}{Página} {de}{Seite} {it}{Pagina} {cs}{Strana}
\do 
   #1#2{\sdef{_mt:page:#1}{#2}}

\headline={\ifodd\pageno \else \hfil \_mtext{page} \the\pageno \fi}
\footline={}

%\eslang  % select language what do you want
\delang
%\itlang
%\cslang

\lipsum[1-50]

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution creating a new macro `\page` that prints the word "page" in different languages (and defaults to english "page" for other languages):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N\g_vebjorn_text_prop
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_vebjorn_text_prop
 {
   english = {Page},
   spanish = {P\acute{a}gina},
   german  = {Seite},
   italian = {Pagina}
 }
\newcommand{\page}
 {
   \prop_get:NVNTF \g_vebjorn_text_prop \languagename \l_tmpa_tl
     { \l_tmpa_tl }
     { \prop_item:Nn \g_vebjorn_text_prop {english} }
 }    
  
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead{
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \else
        \hfill \page\ \thepage
    \fi
    }
}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english,german,italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}

\lipsum[1-50]


\end{document}
```

[image]

This works fine, but I wonder if babel already has something with a similar function.